# jQuery filtrify with pagination, is it possible not to load hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, performance, query-performance

I'm using this jquery solution to filter my content (along with jpages and lazyload) - http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/jpages.html

It works quite good but I've noticed some slowdowns when there are more than 50 elements.
After page has loaded filter itself works fast, but the page loads a bit too long.

I wanted to find out if there is a way to prevent loading of elements (divs in this case), not just images that are not visible?

Can this be achieved with jquery?

Final Code I'm using

```
$(function() {

var container = $("#itemListLeading"),
    pagination = $("#pagination");

function setLazyLoad () {
    container.find("img").lazyload({
        event : "turnPage",
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });
};

function setPagination () {
    pagination.jPages({
        containerID : "itemListLeading",
        perPage : 9,
        direction : "auto",
        animation : "fadeInUp",
        previous  : "a.jprev",
        next      : "a.jnext",
        callback : function( pages, items ){
            items.showing.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
            items.oncoming.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
        }
    });
};

function destroyPagination () {
    pagination.jPages("destroy");
};

setLazyLoad();
setPagination();    

var ft = $.filtrify("itemListLeading", "placeHolder", {
    close: true, // Close windows after tag select
    block : "data-original",
    callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {

        if ( mismatch.length ) $("div#reset").show(); // Show Reset
        else $("div#reset").hide();

        $('.ft-label').parent() // Hide unrelated tags
            .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
            .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();

        $(".ft-selected li").css("display","inline-block"); // small tag display fix

        destroyPagination();
        setPagination();

    }
});

$("div#reset span").click(function() { // Make reset button clickable
    ft.reset();
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that, not sure it can be apply in your case:

```
$(function() {
  $('div:hidden').remove();

  var container = $("#itemListLeading"),
  ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :(
There is also an error for ... in last line before "});"

Comment: Well the '...' means put rest of your code here... So i was telling you to just add to your function `$('div:hidden').remove();` line...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that :)
It looks like this code has helped, page seems to load a lot faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code, but unfortunately it breaks filter functionality. I didn't clear my cache before :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('div:hidden').remove();

var container = $("#itemListLeading"),
    pagination = $("#pagination");

function setLazyLoad () {
    container.find("img").lazyload({
        event : "turnPage",
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });
};

function setPagination () {
    pagination.jPages({
        containerID : "itemListLeading",
        perPage : 9,
        direction : "auto",
        animation : "fadeInUp",
        previous  : "a.jprev",
        next      : "a.jnext",
        callback : function( pages, items ){
            items.showing.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
            items.oncoming.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
        }
    });
};

function destroyPagination () {
    pagination.jPages("destroy");
};

setLazyLoad();
setPagination();    

var ft = $.filtrify("itemListLeading", "placeHolder", {
    close: true, // Close windows after tag select
    block : "data-original",
    callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {

        if ( mismatch.length ) $("div#reset").show(); // Show Reset
        else $("div#reset").hide();

        $('.ft-label').parent() // Hide unrelated tags
            .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
            .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();

        $(".ft-selected li").css("display","inline-block"); // small tag display fix

        destroyPagination();
        setPagination();

    }
});

$("div#reset span").click(function() { // Make reset button clickable
    ft.reset();
});
```

});